# PHP: Loosely Coupled Parameterized Factory. Is it possible?

Tags: php, factory

**My need:**
I want to instantiate an object where the class of the new object is determined by the objects that are given as arguments to a factory method. At the same time I want to keep the factory method loosely coupled so it doesn't need to be updated when I add a new product class. It seems like a parameterized factory like the code below is a solution but is tightly coupled to the product classes.

**What I am doing:**
I am translating between data objects holding essentially the same information in different formats. These need to be translated from one format to the other but I won't know what Class the data objects belong to until they request the translator. I know how the translator is implemented but I'm struggling with how to select the proper translator for a the given objects without making a large series of if that check what class the object belong to. I'm thinking I should use a factory to return the compatible translator based on what class the data objects are instanceof.

**Generic code that 'works' but is tightly coupled:**

```
class Factory {

public static function getTranslator( object $a, object $b ): Product {
    if( ( $a instanceof ClassOne && $b instanceof ClassTwo )
        || ( $a instanceof ClassTwo && $b instanceof ClassOne )
    ) {
        return new TranslatorForClassOneAndTwo( $a, $b );
    }
    if( ( $a instanceof ClassOne && $b instanceof ClassThree )
            || ( $a instanceof ClassThree && $b instanceof ClassOne ) ) {
        return new TranslatorForClassOneAndThree( $a, $b );
    }
    if( ( $a instanceof ClassTwo && $b instanceof ClassThree )
            || ( $a instanceof ClassThree && $b instanceof ClassTwo ) ) {
        return new TranslatorForClassTwoAndThree( $a, $b );
    }
    //...and so on.
}
}
```

**Usage:**

```
    $object_a = new CrmData();
    $object_b = new CmsData();
    $object_c = new MarketingData();

//Translate object_a to object_b 
    $translator_alpha = Factory::getTranslator($object_a , $object_b);
    $translated_object_one = $translator_alpha->translate($object_a , $object_b);

    $translator_beta = Factory::getTranslator($object_a , $object_c);
    $translated_object_two = $translator_beta->translate($object_a , $object_c);

//$translated_object_one is the data of $object_a but same class as $object_b, CmsData
//$translated_object_two is the data of $object_a but same class as $object_c, MarketingData
```

With the above code I need to add a new case to this factory method every time I add a new `Product` class. It would be much preferred if there is a way to instantiate these Products based on the same logic as above without having to explicitly define each case. It seems possible there is a way to do this using some OO structure but I am out of ideas. Also, it would be helpful to know if this is currently impossible in php and I am stuck using the more explicit structure if there is no good solution.

Comment: What's the logic behind? How your program is supposed to know which product it should instantiate based on initial classes passed?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I updated my question to hopefully make it more clear. The tl;dr is that, in the code above, the classes of the two arguments passed into `Factory::getProduct()` determine what product needs to be instantiated.

Comment: Can the logic be expressed in any way that can be coded without requiring a new case to be added every time a new product is added? Right now it seems very specific and hard to abstract...

Comment: It's still hard to understand how to translate. If you can't describe in words, probably you will not be able to do the same with code. Try to describe your logic first, and then you can try to code.

Comment: @deceze That is a great way of restating my question. I don't really know. I know I need to use the class of the two data objects to determine the correct translator. Even if I defined an interface that was implemented by all the data objects (which would be a pain since I would need to make a wrapper for all the classes) I would still need this logic at some place along the way to determine which translator knows how to translate between 2 specific classes. I originally hoped that I could use some sort of inheritance structure to select the correct translator but that seems like a dead end.

Comment: Can two object combinations be translated by the same translator? In other words, can a same translator be instantiated in two different scenarii, or is there exactly one "dedicated" translator by combination?

Comment: @Jeto Since these translations are fairly involved and complicated there is a subclass of Translator for each of the combinations. Each translator can translate in either direction but only between the the two specific object classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility (different from my other answer and closer to your own):

- the `Translator` objects respond to `canTranslateBetween(Translatable, Translatable): bool` (this can be contractually defined as an abstract static method in PHP, btw),
- the `Factory` takes an array of translator classes as a dependency (constructor argument) then instantiates the right one among them.

Your Factory class would look something like this:

```
class TranslatorFactory
{
  /** @var string[] */
  private $translatorClasses;

  public function __construct(array $translatorClasses)
  {
    $this->translatorClasses = $translatorClasses;
  }

  public function createTranslator(Translatable $a, Translatable $b): Translator
  {
    foreach ($this->translatorClasses as $translatorClass) {
      if ($translatorClass::canTranslateBetween($a, $b)) {
        return new $translatorClass;
      }
    }
    throw new \RuntimeException('Could not find translator.');
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
$translatorFactory = new TranslatorFactory([
  Translator1::class, 
  Translator2::class, 
  Translator3::class
]);

$translatable1 = new Translatable1();
$translatable3 = new Translatable3();
$translator = $translatorFactory->createTranslator($translatable1, $translatable3);
```

This has the advantage of being clean and non-hackish in any way (no "magic" or reflection or anything of the likes). The only downside is well, having to list all the translation classes manually upon instantiating the factory, but I feel like this actually makes sense: after all, it will pick one among them.

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/nfuB2**

Comment: Thank you for taking a continued interest in my question. This may be the best solution. If I wasn't using auto loading I could use `get_declared_classes()` and some quick checks to auto populate the list of Translators. As is it requires me to manually load everything for `get_declared_classes()' to see them it is a bit too painful to be worth it. I wonder if there is a way around that?

The great thing is that I can implement this solution and it always leaves me the option to implement an auto populate in the future if it becomes viable I am marking this as the solution..

Comment: You're welcome, it was actually a pretty fun/challenging question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Since translators are both unique and specific to each translatable, you could have a simple naming scheme for your translator classes and load them based on that.

```
public static function getTranslator(Translatable $a, Translatable $b): Translator
{
  $translatorNamespace = (new \ReflectionClass(BaseTranslator::class))->getNamespaceName();
  $translatorClassName = $translatorNamespace 
      . '\\TranslatorFor' . (new \ReflectionClass($a))->getShortName() 
      . 'And' . (new \ReflectionClass($b))->getShortName();
  return new $translatorClassName();
}
```

And if you can't name your actual translator classes that strictly, you could use [`class_alias`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) to create appropriate aliases.

**Demo (with namespaces): https://3v4l.org/KvsAL**

Comment: This has the desired behavior but also a potentially bad side effect that anyone in the future modifying the code will need to know about this naming expectation. While it solves the problem I'm unsure if it is better or worse than having to modify the factory method when I add new data classes. .

Comment: @j-penguin If you're using aliases, you could have your `class_alias` calls at the top of each translator class definition, in which case it should be obvious enough that new ones should follow that same logic.

Comment: That is a little better. Combined with comments it could be an acceptable but slightly less that ideal solution. Thanks for the input, I will mark this as the solution in a couple days if nothing better comes along.

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate your logic to some array, but still you have no abstraction, but will make it easy to configure.
The first option will be the first class to compare with `$a`, the second will be the class to compare with `$b` and the third will be the return object instance:

```
<?php

class ClassOne {}
class ClassTwo {}
class ClassThree {}
class Product {}
class ProductOne extends Product {}
class ProductTwo extends Product {}
class ProductThree extends Product {}

class Factory {
    public static function getProduct(object $a, object $b): Product {
        $array = [
            ['ClassOne','ClassTwo', 'ProductOne'],
            ['ClassTwo','ClassOne', 'ProductOne'],
            ['ClassOne','ClassThree', 'ProductTwo'],
            ['ClassThree','ClassOne', 'ProductTwo'],
            ['ClassThree','ClassTwo', 'ProductTwo'],
            ['ClassTwo','ClassThree', 'ProductThree'],
        ];

        foreach($array as $classes) {
            if (get_class($a) == $classes[0] && get_class($b) == $classes[1]) {
                return new $classes[2];
            }
        }
    }
}


$a = new ClassOne;
$b = new ClassThree;

$x = Factory::getProduct($a, $b);
var_dump($x); //output object(ProductTwo)#3 (0) {}
```

Comment: I up voted but it doesn't show because I am new. This does make it easier to update and is easier to read. I've also considered using an external config to populate something like this but that is likely  not quite worth the work. I'm still holding out for ideas how to gain the abstraction I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack. I think it could work but it might be a bad idea. It also doesn't seem to work with auto loading.

First, make sure all Translator sub-classes are loaded.

Then:

```
    class Factory {

        public static function getTranslator( object $a, object $b ): Translator {
            foreach( get_declared_classes() as $class ) {
                if( is_subclass_of( $class, ObjectTranslator::class ) ) {
                    $translator[] = $class;
                }
            }

            foreach($translator as $child) {
                if($child::isCompatible($object_a, $object_b)) {
                    return new $child();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What do you think. Good idea? Bad Idea? Burn this before someone sees it? Why?

My big concern is that it implicitly requires all the subclasses to be loaded, which is not intuitive. It also might be slowed down by the reflection but that could be tested.